# Tkinter GUI closing - release memory automatically

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a small Tkinter root gui which has 3 buttons.

Question: is closing this root gui instance through the default `x` icon in runtime , taking care of releasing of memory used or any other memory management stuff, or do I specifically have to use some sort of: `root.destroy()` ?

```
root = Tk()

root.geometry('700x200')
root.resizable(height = 0, width = 0)
root.title("eWMS Inbound Upload File")

Label(root,text="Browse for source file to be converted to the eWMS format").place(x=200,y=50)
Label(root,text="Generate eWMS format template and Save on Computer").place(x=200,y=80)
Label(root,text="Select XLS File and Convert it to CSV with separator semicolon( ; ) ").place(x=200,y=110)

Button(root, text="Select Source File",command=openfile, width=20).place(x=10,y=50)
Button(root, text="Convert to Upload Format",command=createtemplate,width=20).place(x=10,y=80)
Button(root, text="Convert XLS to CSV",command=convertocsv,width=20).place(x=10,y=110)

root.mainloop()
```

Edit: this whole code is build into an .exe file through the "pyinstaller" library

Comment: If the program exits as a result of closing the window, then you don't have to worry about releasing memory, as you no longer have a process that's able to *have* any allocated memory.

Comment: @jasonharper yes, it exits normal without any issues. Thanks for the clarifications!